# Avg,max dissimilarity,isolation=0 for certain clusters after using Clara() on R

Tags: r, clustering

I found the best k value after running a silhouette test to get k=21. On running clara() on the dataset of 13805 points, I found a pretty interesting trend: Non-zero memberships, but zero values of average, max dissimilarity on R, specifically for clusters **2,4,9,10,15,16,17,18 & 19**.

The data set represents demand frequency from different locations. You will find that there is a fair amount of repetition.I need to cluster all these demand points as they represent a sample demand scenario.

Data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/anv7791olo8fur0/Demand.csv?dl=0

Cluster image: [image]

**R Code**

```
    #find k value for 13805 demand points. 
    > shadowsize<-numeric(91)
    > for(i in 10:100)
    +     shadowsize[[i]]<-clara(a13kinput4clara,i)$silinfo$avg.width
    > which.max(shadowsize)
    [1] 21
    > set.seed(123432341)
    > clara13k<-clara(a13kinput4clara,21)
    >clara13k$clusinfo
             size    max_diss  av_diss   isolation
       [1,]  313    0.0153895 0.0031959   0.7490261
       [2,] 1205        0         0           0 
       [3,]  439    0.0482945 0.0001100  1.2317786
       [4,] 1029        0         0           0
       [5,]  597 0.066592748 0.0009597415 1.8877388
       [6,]  384 0.130181675 0.0102797877 1.7529969
       [7,]  309 0.114705153 0.0003712141 1.0298820
       [8,] 1403 0.008978207 0.0018877912 0.2847452
       [9,]  136        0         0           0
      [10,]  764        0         0           0
      [11,]  268 0.114271631 0.0023798307 1.9138448
      [12,]  429 0.026879530 0.0001879687 1.3082594
      [13,]  691 0.032642864 0.0005439049 1.1087782
      [14,]  798 0.142868007 0.0010571184 2.5221135
      [15,]  385        0         0           0
      [16,] 1194        0         0           0
      [17,]  850        0         0           0
      [18,]  429        0         0           0
      [19,] 1108        0         0           0
      [20,]    5        0         0           0
      [21,] 1069 0.112005995 0.0006286585 2.0899605
```

**Questions**

1. Are the zero values characteristic of outliers? Why is this happening? Could it be because of the significant demand point overlap (for certain locations)?
2. I used Clara() as I understood it was a variant of pam(). Is the Clara() function flawed? Are there any alternatives I can use for k-medoid clustering of such fairly large datasets,if so?

Thank You in advance,

Metalxenophobe

Comment: Any chance these "clusters" have 1 element each? Try removing outliers.

Comment: As you have several points with a given lat-long value, I suspect the overlapped set is being translated into a cluster. Also, doesn't size talk of the number of points in the cluster?

Comment: Sorry. Missed that column. Could still be duplicates! Can you check the clusters for duplicates.

Comment: Yes, there are duplicates. I need to use all of the demand points. However, I find the max frequency of demand repetition is nowhere near the values of cluster membership being churned out by the algorithm for the clusters I mentioned. Not sure if this is a legit result ,in that context. I hope I've conveyed my problem.:P

Comment: Analyze the individual clusters. max_diss 0 indicates they are all duplicates.

Comment: You're right, Anony-Mousse. There was a repetition of elements in those clusters with 0,0,0. I also checked the clusters after adding some additional commands,i.e., lines=0, labels=4. Seems legit. I need all the data points for clustering.

Just wondering aloud: Would DBSCAN have been a better option?

Comment: from the visualization, i'd say there are no clusters, except for the duplicates. how does a dendrogram look like? Maybe after you remove duplicates and outliers the picture changes.

Comment: But, don't the Voronoi cells( ellipse objects) constitute clusters?